# How to set Right align in one column of a table using codeigniter

Tags: html, codeigniter, class, html-table

I am  new to codeigniter. I used the class HTML Table to display results.

I have two columns. First column is Description and Second column is Amount. I want to display the amount in right align as it is in currency.

Is there any possible way to do it?

Comment: Actually, I haven't solved this issue using the HTML TABLE class of codeigniter as it is limited to manipulate the <TD> column. Im not sure if there are other ways which I haven't think nor tried. If you have some idea how to do this using the HTML table class of codeigniter, please feel free to post your comments here.

Anyways, I just used the normal HTML and do the FOR-EACH statement and produced my desired result which is, the align the second column at Right.

Comment: The easiest & best way to do this - assign a class to the <td> with set_template() or in the row creation if that is how you are doing it.  Then use CSS on that class to align it. You can also use this technique to do all kinds of formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this->load->library('table');

$this->table->set_heading(array('Description', array('data' => 'Amount', 'align' => 'right')));

$this->table->add_row('Description 1', array('data' => '$1.99', 'align' => 'right'));

echo $this->table->generate();
```

Any key you add to the array other than data will become an attribute on the td or th

Answer (score 0):

Set your table template read this **http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/table.html**

```
$tmpl = array (
                    'table_open'          => '<table border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0">',

                    'heading_row_start'   => '<tr>',
                    'heading_row_end'     => '</tr>',
                    'heading_cell_start'  => '<th>',
                    'heading_cell_end'    => '</th>',

                    'row_start'           => '<tr>',
                    'row_end'             => '</tr>',
                    'cell_start'          => '<td>',
                    'cell_end'            => '</td>',

                    'row_alt_start'       => '<tr>',
                    'row_alt_end'         => '</tr>',
                    'cell_alt_start'      => '<td>',
                    'cell_alt_end'        => '</td>',

                    'table_close'         => '</table>'
              );

$this->table->set_template($tmpl);
```

Comment: Hi Arif, thanks a lot for your comment.I have already done this procedure.I add this code as specified in the documentation of codeigniter. However, there is no portion which you can manipulate the TD part of a table.As in my issue. I have two columns. The second column must be aligned to right as this is an amount field. As I can see, there is this parameter "cell_alt_start", but how will I tell that the 2nd column will only be aligned to right and the 1st column as aligned to left? I think its not possible at this time. Or I am not sure if there are other means or ways that I have not tried.